# Error submitting to WindowsPhone 8 App Store: We weren't able to save your info. Try again. Error code: 0x80040803

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I have seen this error reported a few times when submitting apps to the Windows Phone 8 store

> We weren't able to save your info. Try again. Error code: 0x80040803.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in my case was a duplicate entry in the WMAppManifest.xml file

The error is caused by a duplicate capability entry in the WMAppManifest.xml file:

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA" />
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS" />
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA" />
```

After correcting this the problem is resolved and the app was successfully submitted. Hope this helps someone developing for Windows Phone 8

Comment: Recommendation: Run the Validation Tool build into Visual Studio, before submitting.

Comment: Jonny, how did you found where the problem is?